# get distinct count and name using linq from dataset table

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm fairly new to LINQ using VB.Net. I got to know that its quite fast in fetching results.

I have a dataset with a table and want to retrieve distinct values with the count

The data is represented by (around 50,000 lines of csv)

p1.pdf
e3.xls
d1.doc
p2.pdf
e2.xls
d2.doc
p1.pdf
e3.xls
d2.doc
d4.doc

would like to have like this

p1.pdf - 2 
p2.pdf - 1 
e3.xls - 2 
e2.xls - 1 
d2.doc - 2 
d1.doc - 1 
d4.doc - 1

I have tried something like this

```
Dim Filtered = From row in ds.tables("AuditLog").AsEnumerables()
               Where (row.Field(Of String)("DocName") Like "*.pdf")

Dim dt as New Datatable
dt = Filtered.CopyToDataTable
```

This gives the list of all pdfs, and I could use the dataview to get the count, but if there is a faster way in getting the count, it would be great

Please help me if possible

Thanks for your patience

Comment: 1) Groupby name, 2) Select new object with as property the name of the groupby and an int, count of the elements 3) Orderby last 3 characters of groupname. In C# it would look something like: `table.GroupBy(t => t.DocName).Select(t => new { name = t.Key, count = t.Count() }.OrderBy(t => t.name.Substring(t.name.Length-3));`

Comment: Hi Alexander, im sure that this would be a correct answer, but I have no idea about C#, and would take me more time in decoding the same. If you could help me in converting the same in vb.net, i would be very grateful

Comment: Just saying the algorithm you need, all the same methods are available in vb.net but I don't know the syntax :/

Comment: Hi Alexander, thank you for your effort

Comment: Daniel Drews to the rescue with the correct syntax ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim dr As DataRow
    Dim nameCoulumn As DataColumn

    dt = New DataTable("files")
    nameCoulumn = New DataColumn("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add(nameCoulumn)

    dr = dt.NewRow()
    dr("Name") = "p1.pdf"
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)

    dr = dt.NewRow()
    dr("Name") = "e3.xls"
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)

    dr = dt.NewRow()
    dr("Name") = "p2.pdf"
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)

    dr = dt.NewRow()
    dr("Name") = "p1.pdf"
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)

    Dim query = From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
                Group row By name = row.Field(Of String)("Name") Into g = Group
    Select New With {
        Key name,
        .Count = g.Count()
        }

    For Each row In query
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", row.name, row.Count.ToString()))
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you daniel. Life saver